# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS performLoginDelegateQueue in iOS

Tags: ios

crashlytics shows me a crash like below. Why does this error occur?How can I overcome this crash ? I updated my question in code part

**Related code part :**

```
     -(void)loginUser:(id)delegate returnSelector:(SEL)selector
  {
                if (delegate != nil) {
                        LoginDelegate* loginDelegate = [[LoginDelegate alloc] init];
                        loginDelegate.returnDelegate = delegate;
                        loginDelegate.returnSelector = selector;
                        [self.loginDelegateQueue addObject:loginDelegate];
                    }
                .....

                  ....

              [self performLoginDelegateQueue];

 }



             - (void)performLoginDelegateQueue
 {
               for (LoginDelegate* loginDelegate in self.loginDelegateQueue) {
                                [loginDelegate.returnDelegate performSelector:loginDelegate.returnSelector];
                }
                [self clearLoginDelegateQueue];                  
 }
```

**Crashlytics Report :**

```
  Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
    0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1835040b0 objc_retain + 16
    1  MyApp                     0x1000e66d8 -[UserController performLoginDelegateQueue] (UserController.m:135)
    2  MyApp                     0x1000e6180 __43-[UserController loginUser:returnSelector:]_block_invoke (UserController.m:63)
    3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1838d1630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1838d15f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1838d6cf8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
    6  CoreFoundation                 0x183e34bb0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
    7  CoreFoundation                 0x183e32a18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628
    8  CoreFoundation                 0x183d61680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    9  GraphicsServices               0x185270088 GSEventRunModal + 180
    10 UIKit                          0x188bd8d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
    11 MyApp                     0x1000bd734 main (main.m:16)
    12 libdispatch.dylib              0x1839028b8 (Missing)
```

**LoginDelegate.h**

```
@interface LoginDelegate : NSObject

@property (unsafe_unretained) id returnDelegate;
@property (unsafe_unretained) SEL returnSelector;

@end
```

Comment: On which line you getting crash ?

Comment: it occurs when call performLoginDelegateQueue

Comment: on this line [loginDelegate.returnDelegate performSelector:loginDelegate.returnSelector]; ?

Comment: Please provide more code, so we can help you.

Comment: I added some details

Comment: I am not getting exact solution , but i think [UserController loginUser:returnSelector:] implement some block execution. So debug at that point.